# codaslider 2.0 - two sliders on one page

Tags: jquery, slider

I recently have had to update a website.

codaslider 2.0 is used.https://github.com/KevinBatdorf
And my update it to now have 2 sliders on the one page.

I have the two sliders working. But when i scroll the 2nd slider, it conflicts with the first slider. I think it is a deep linking issue. So when im on slide three for both sliders, the url extension will be html#3.

```
$().ready(function() {
            $("#coda-slider-1").css("visibility", "visible");
            $('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider();
            $("#coda-slider-2").css("visibility", "visible");
            $('#coda-slider-2').codaSlider();
            //$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:100}, 'slow');
        });
```

Comment: plz post a sample on jsfiddle

Comment: i tried to lol. didnt get it working. hmmph

Comment: I cant do a fiddle. but here is a link. http://adl.clemenger.com.au/adamexperiment/littlesavers%20copy/tips-and-lessons.html
if you play around with both sliders. you'll see my issue.